# Angular.js : child not getting parent's variables

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, components

I find myself needing to write up this code: `vm.model = $scope.$parent.$ctrl.model`, in order to access variables that I felt should be readily available in the child. How can I have them injected seamlessly.

Comment: Sounds like a use case for intercomponent communication. You can access the parent variables using `bindings` https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication

Comment: Is there a reason these variables don't belong in the scope of the parent? Scope variables are cloned into child scopes.